# render_to_string breaks action rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

In my controller I want to render one of the HTML partials into a string variable, then send it with the Pusher and finalize the action with a regular rendering of the JS file (this is AJAX request).

I'm making an AJAX call and my action looks like this:

```
def create
    @my_Object = ...
    @html_content = escape_javascript(render_to_string :partial => 'my_partial', :object => @my_object )
    Pusher.trigger(
        'my-channel',
        'my-event',
        { message: @html_content }
    )
end
```

Given my understanding I would expect to see the "create.js" file being rendered at the end of this action, but this is not the case.

If in the "create.js" I put:
    alert("test");

I do not see the dialog even though in rails logs I do see that the "create.js" partial is rendered.

When I remove the render_to_string part all works fine and the "create.js" gets properly rendered.

Can you help? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the fix is to explicitly call
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end

after the render_to_string.

This is strange as without the render_to_string call you do no thave to do that...